# Angular | Typscript | mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, caption, mat-table

I am using mat-table from Angular.

I have to set a Caption for a Table.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" id=tbl_suchergebnis>
      <caption>
        description...
      </caption>
    <!-- Name Column -->
    ...
  </table>
```

But the mat table does not accept this syntax. Maybe someone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi instead table use can use this way

```
<mat-table .......>
<caption> Description </caption>

</mat-table>
```

it seems to be working for me....

Comment: I had test it, but without success